# MongoDB connection string in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb with nodejs. My mongodb utility has the following code

In mongodbUtil.js:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

var state = {
    db: null,
}

exports.connect = function(url, done) {
    if (state.db) return done()

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) return done(err)
        state.db = db
        done()
    })
}

exports.get = function() {
    return state.db
}


/* 1 : when is close called */
exports.close = function(done) {
    if (state.db) {
        state.db.close(function(err, result) {
            state.db = null
            state.mode = null
            done(err)
        })
    }
}
```

In app.js I have the following code

```
var async = require("async");
var express = require("express");
var app =  express();
var db = require("./mongodbUtil");



db.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to Mongo.')
        process.exit(1)
    } else {
        app.listen(3000, function() {
            console.log('Listening on port 3000...')
        })
    }
})


app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.send("routes :/insert ")

})


app.get('/insert',function(req,res){

    var collection = db.get().collection('insertcollection');
    collection.drop();
    var obj = {};

    for (i=0; i <100000 ; i++){
        obj=({id: i, square:i*i,sum:i+i,subtract:i-1,data:"data part 2014"});

        collection.insert(obj.table, function (err, result) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);

            } else {
                console.log(i);
            }
        });
    }

})
```

I have the following query in this code

1. When should I close the connection in mongodb ? Is this handled by nodejs mongodb driver implicitly or it will just create a connection
   pool in this scenario ?
2. Should I set the connection string with read preference and write preference or should I leave it as the default value ?
3. In the insert route only ~60000 records are inserted in the collection. I don't see any error in the mongodb insert callback too.  Is there a particular reason why only partial data is dumped ? (I know that bulk insert is better in performance but I am curious about why no error was reported and only partial data was dumped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several option, you could create a new connection for every request or have a pool of connections, or if you don't have high traffic as you did, one connection is fine.

For the closing part, if you close it in your request, if you request again that route, you will have an error. Let nodejs mongodb driver handle it.

For the partial data, you are doing a synchronous loop to execute asynchronous call. Change your code to this :

```
const promises = [];
for (i=0; i <100000 ; i++){
    promises.push(
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            obj={id: i, square:i*i,sum:i+i,subtract:i-1,data:"data part 2014"};
            collection.insert(obj.table, function (err, result) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return reject(err);
                } 
                console.log(i);
                return resolve(i);
            });
        })
    );
}

Promise.all(promises)
.then((result) => {
    // if no error in calls
    console.log(reslt);
})
.catch((error) => {
    // if error in calls
});
```

But, if you are using the native mongodb driver, you can use `col.insertMany()` which basically takes a table of objects. This way :

```
  const objs = [];
  for (i=0; i <100000 ; i++){
      objs.push({id: i, square:i*i,sum:i+i,subtract:i-1,data:"data part 2014"});
  }

  col.insertMany(
      objs, 
      function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
              console.error(err);
              return;
          }
          console.log(result);
      }
  );
```

Hope this helps

Comment: so if I have a high traffic requirement and use connection pooling ,does that mean i do not need to close the connection at any point during the lifetime of the nodejs application .

Comment: I would not advise to close the connection, but I would advise to have wrapper around the way you get the connection, to make sure there are open connections, if not reopen one or more and add them to the pool.

Comment: And if a open connection fails during the lifetime of the nodejs application what would be the best way to respawn the mongodb connection.Also if the code for /insert route was synchronous why was it able to dump 60k records and not error out in the error callback